# The leftmost character above is illegal in an expression

Tags: autohotkey, mouse

I am trying to assign a mouse move to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> using this line:

```
^q::MouseMove, 100, 100; moves mouse to northwest
```

But it results in an error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a space between the last character and semicolon if you nwant to make a comment on the same line in ahk.

```
 ^q::MouseMove, 100, 100; moves mouse to northwest <- this will fail.
 ^q::MouseMove, 100, 100 ; moves mouse to northwest <- this works.
```